# DCount will nor return 0 but returns Error instead

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
Test = DCount("*", "tblWorkNew", "GP = " & GPID & " And Month = #" & Month & "#")
```

This function gives correct results when the answer is >0. Whenever it's 0, I get #Error. I have tried putting my code within a Nz but that doesn't help either.

Comment: In your table, what data type is 'Month'? I get an error because it doesn't like the '#' -- and I have tried every combination of numeric/non-numeric field type and parameter type. I get it to run if I remove the #'s.

Comment: Is your Month variable a numeric value or is it the month name?

Comment: Month is Date/Time in my table. In other bits of coding in the same form I got an error unless I used #. On my form Month is constructed from DateSerial, as I need to specify the date of the last day in any given month.

Comment: If 'Month' is defined as DateTime in your table, then your above Dcount will never work correctly - unless the parameter 'Month' you are passing is actually a full date (i.e. mm/dd/yyyy).  Why would you name a field using a reserved word, and something that is totally confusing to anyone else? Now, is the parameter you pass a full date?

Comment: I made a comment a short while ago - can't see it so here it is again: parameter I am passing is a full date as far as I can tell e.g. 31/03/2013. Have got rid of the reserved word. N.B. my code works fine provided it returns a value >0.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to duplicate on a Northwind db what I believe you are trying to do. I used the Order List form. In the header of that form I created a textbox named txtMonth. The Control Source for txtMonth is =Month([Order Date]). Then I created another textbox in the header named txtMonthOrders with Control Source as =GetMonthSum(). Then I created a function in Modules called GetMonthSum(). This is the function: GetMonthSum = DCount("[Order ID]", "Order Summary", "Month([Order Date]) = '" & Forms![Order List]!txtMonth & "'") . This seems to work.